# convert properties file in arabic to unicode

Tags: unicode

I have a requirement where a client will supply properties file in arabic where i have to convert the file(arabic.properties) to unicode. The file contains more than 500 lines.please help me to write the code to convert "arabic character" to "unicode character".

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using command line go to Java folder, and write:

```
\Java\bin>native2ascii -encoding utf-8 Labels_ar.txt Labels_ar.properties
```

**UPDATE**
Not sure what exactly you mean by not proper, but try this scenario:
Open notepad and write something in Arabic: let's say:

```
MyLabel = تجربه1
```

Then save it as test.txt and make sure to choose *UTF-8* from *Encoding*.

Now from the command line:

```
native2ascii -encoding utf-8 test.txt test_ar.properties
```

Now test_ar.properties contain:

```
MyLabel = \u062a\u062c\u0631\u0628\u06471
```

Notice, sometimes native2ascii might add `\ufeff` as the first character in the file. You will need to remove it manually if you found it.

Comment: I tried this but conversion is not proper

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the client is supplying the file encoded in [codepage 1256 (Windows Arabic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195058.aspx). I'm further guessing that by Unicode you actually mean UTF-8 encoding. If that's correct, then the following Python 3 script would do this:

```
with open("arabic.properties", "r", encoding="cp1256") as infile:
    with open("utf8.properties", "w", encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
        outfile.write(infile.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you first have to know the *encoding* of the file they're going to give you. "Arabic characters" may describe what individual graphemes you may encounter but, without the encoding, it'll be like trying to *train a cat* or *nail jelly to a tree.*

With any luck, they'll *give* you one of the Unicode encodings (UTF-8, UCS-2, etc) and the "conversion" will be relatively painless.

Comment: @user930692 Then it is **already in Unicode**, so no conversion is needed.

Comment: sorry i meant arabic to UTF-8 encoding